# How can I encrypt Google Chrome passwords?

Tags: google-chrome, password, encryption, google

I want to know how to encrypt Google Chrome passwords so that no one can show it. There is no option for a master password to encrypt passwords saved on Chrome browser, and I want to make it more secure

Comment: Nice read: http://www.howtogeek.com/70146/how-secure-are-your-saved-chrome-browser-passwords/

Answer (score 4):

You can use an external password safe with strong encryption. I use keepass2 for that. It has plugins for firefox and chrome/chromium.

To install keepass2 you can use

```
sudo apt-get install keepass2 keepass2-plugin-keepasshttp keepass2-plugin-rpc keepass2-plugin-application-menu keepass2-plugin-application-indicator
```

ChromeIPass is installed from the chrome webstore:

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chromeipass/ompiailgknfdndiefoaoiligalphfdae

Comment: i am using keepass2 and the mentioned plugins but the autofill function not as good as chrome built in autofill function!!. i want to know if i used something like lastpass it will help me and provide a secure autofill function?